# What is the worst case run-time of this knapsack algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I have the following algorithm:

```
function KP-O-APPROXIMATE(n,c,W,V)
    Initialize L as a list of n numbers
    for i from 1 to n do 
        l_i <- 0
    end for
    repeat
       x <- 0 ; d <- 0 ;
       for i from 1 to n do 
          if l_i = 0 and w_i <= c_i then
              if v_i/w_i > d then
                   x <- 1; d <- (v_i / w_i)
              end if
          end if
        end for
        if x≠0 then 
             l_x <- 1; c <- c - w_x
        end if
    until x=0
    return L
 end function
```

What is the worst-case run time for this algorithm? So far I have that $n$ the worst case, the algorithm will iterate over all $n$ items in each iteration of the loop and will select an item to add to the knapsack in each iteration until no more items can be taken. This means that the algorithm will make at most $n$ iterations of the loop, and in each iteration, it will perform $n$ comparisons to select an item. Therefore, the worst-case runtime of this algorithm is $O(n^2)$.

Does this make sense? Or is there logic that I am missing.

Comment: It is not clear to me what ```x=\0``` is.

Comment: This seems to be an almost verbatim copy of your previous question [Solving worst case run time for this algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671638/solving-worst-case-run-time-for-this-algorithm). Please don't do that; it wastes everyone's time. (I posted an answer to that question saying that your conclusion is correct, but it was deleted because five people thought that it didn't answer the question. Perhaps you have an opinion on that?)

Comment: @joriki I meant to delete my other post as it had been downvoted for having a picture. Not trying to waste anyone’s time.